# Large files on C: drive under a directory called PC Health?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6

I'm running a website on a Windows Server 2003 machine, though I disabled IIS Log entirely, My C:\ Drive continues growing in a very weird way. I found a directory with almost 30 GB of space; this directory is called PCHealth .. can I delete the files in this directory safely? or are they required for a vital application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This folder records information about your system, its state and any changes to the system. If you run Disk Cleanup, it should delete non-essential data from this folder for you. I would not recommend just deleting its entire contents, as you may lose access to some information about your system.

Comment: The problem is that I can't run Disk Cleanup, it takes forever! 
PS: I'm having only 13 MB free space on my C:\ Drive

Comment: With those size files, cleanup will take some time, its unfortunate, but not alot can be done about it. Are there any other areas of the diks you can cleanup in the meantime to give you some breathing room while you run cleanup?

Comment: The DC admin in my farm already deleted the files :S

Answer (score 0):

yes disk cleanup helps
generally pchealth stores compressed old files
u can see in disk cleanup options

-Sasikiran